# Firebase Push Notification Giving Error like 'int java.lang.Integer.intValue()' on a null object reference

Tags: flutter, dart, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-push-notification

Here is the Class of Local Notification Service which will Call while the Notification Came

```
class LocalNotificationService {
  static final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin _notificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  static void initialize() {
    // initializationSettings  for Android
    const InitializationSettings initializationSettings =
        InitializationSettings(
      android: AndroidInitializationSettings("@mipmap/ic_launcher"),
    );
    _notificationsPlugin.initialize(
      initializationSettings,
      onDidReceiveBackgroundNotificationResponse: (details) {
        print("details Data : ${details.payload}");
        if (details.payload == 'Offer Section' && details.payload != null) {
          if (tokenValue != null) {
            Navigator.push(
                navigatorkey.currentContext!,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => OfferMeScreen(),
                ));
          }
        } else if (details.payload == 'Surprise Me Section' &&
            details.payload != null) {
          Navigator.push(
              navigatorkey.currentContext!,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => HomeScreen(index: 2),
              ));
        } else if (Provider.of<GeneralController>(navigatorkey.currentContext!,
                        listen: false)
                    .notification_name ==
                'Restaurant' &&
            Provider.of<GeneralController>(navigatorkey.currentContext!,
                        listen: false)
                    .notification_name !=
                null) {
          Provider.of<FoodController>(navigatorkey.currentContext!,
                  listen: false)
              .restaurantDetailApi(navigatorkey.currentContext!,
                  id: details.payload);
        }
      },
      onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: (details) {
        print("details Data : ${details.payload}");
        if (details.payload == 'Offer Section' && details.payload != null) {
          if (tokenValue != null) {
            Navigator.push(
                navigatorkey.currentContext!,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => OfferMeScreen(),
                ));
          }
        } else if (details.payload == 'Surprise Me Section' &&
            details.payload != null) {
          Navigator.push(
              navigatorkey.currentContext!,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => HomeScreen(index: 2),
              ));
        } else if (Provider.of<GeneralController>(navigatorkey.currentContext!,
                        listen: false)
                    .notification_name ==
                'Restaurant' &&
            Provider.of<GeneralController>(navigatorkey.currentContext!,
                        listen: false)
                    .notification_name !=
                null) {
          Provider.of<FoodController>(navigatorkey.currentContext!,
                  listen: false)
              .restaurantDetailApi(navigatorkey.currentContext!,
                  id: details.payload);
        }
      },
    );
  }

  static void createanddisplaynotification(RemoteMessage message) async {
    try {
      final id = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch ~/ 1000;
      const NotificationDetails notificationDetails = NotificationDetails(
        android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
          "ikwteat_push_notification",
          "ikwteatpushnotificationappchannel",
          importance: Importance.max,
          priority: Priority.high,
        ),
      );
      Map<String, dynamic> data = message.data;
      String linkTo = data['notification_link_to'];

      if (linkTo == 'Restaurant') {
        print('object');
        Provider.of<GeneralController>(navigatorkey.currentContext!,
                listen: false)
            .updateNotification(value: linkTo);
        if (data['restaurant_id'] != null) {
          linkTo = data['restaurant_id'];
          print("Restaurant Id : ${linkTo}");
        }
      }
      print('Notfication id ${id.runtimeType}');
      await _notificationsPlugin.show(
        id,
        message.notification!.title,
        message.notification!.body,
        notificationDetails,
        payload: linkTo,
      );
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Here are the Firebase Function which Are handling different states of Notifications like Background , foreground and Terminated

```
void FirebaseFunctions() {

  // 1. This method call when app in terminated state and you get a notification
  // when you click on notification app open from terminated state and you can get notification data in this method
  FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage().then(
    (message) {
      print("FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage");
      if (message != null) {
        print("New Notification");
        
      }
    },
  );

 
  FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen(
    (message) {
      print("FirebaseMessaging.oneMssage.listen");
      if (message.notification != null) {
        print(message.notification!.title);
        print(message.notification!.body);
        Map<String, dynamic> data = message.data;
        String linkTo = data['notification_link_to'];
        print("Link to  ${linkTo}");
        LocalNotificationService.createanddisplaynotification(message);
      }
    },
  );

  // 3. This method only call when App in background and not terminated(not closed)
  FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen(
    (message) {
      print("FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen");
      if (message.notification != null) {
        print(message.notification!.title);
        print(message.notification!.body);
        // print("message.data22 ${message.data['_id']}");
        LocalNotificationService.createanddisplaynotification(message);
      }
    },
  );
}
```

when the Notification come it keeps giving me the Error like

```
D/CompatibilityChangeReporter( 2009): Compat change id reported: 160794467; UID 11103; state: ENABLED
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications( 2009): Failed to handle method call
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications( 2009): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.Integer.intValue()' on a null object reference
```

I couldn't understand where i am reading integer value if any body knows where i am going wrong please help me out

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is that your app icon is not being present in the `android/app/src/main/res/drawable` folder or that it might be broken in any other way.

You can read more about it in a GitHub issue - it sums up as the following:

> If you're using Android Studio right click on res folder in main
> directory > Select new > Image Asset. Change Icon type to
> 'Notification Icons'. Set whatever clip art, image you want to set and
> give it a name copy the name and pass that name to
> AndroidInitializationSettings('app_icon') in place of 'app_icon'. This
> will stop the crash because now the app has a legit icon for the
> notifications.
>
> Make sure to stop and rerun the app completely to apply the changes.

See [here](https://github.com/MaikuB/flutter_local_notifications/issues/220).

Comment: i think  _notificationsPlugin.initialize Function is Causing issue because it didn't have values which he required to perform operation how can i reslove this issue

Comment: Functions which have values runs afterwards

Comment: Do you use proguard?

Comment: No i didn't use that ,

Comment: It is important that you initialize everything before receive your first notification. Is that the case?

Comment: i initialize  _notificationsPlugin.initialize that function in the main.dart and afterwards Foreground, Background and Terminated state functions runs which have notification Values